# ThreeJS / Angular - OBJLoader was not found

Tags: angular, three.js

I'm trying to use ThreeJS within Angular and especially the OBJLoader to render .obj files.

However, I'm getting an error

> "export 'OBJLoader' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'

Here is my code part

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import * as OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader';
OBJLoader(THREE);
console.log(typeof THREE.OBJLoader);





const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

objLoader.load(
  // resource URL
  '../../assets/icon/threed/helicopter.obj',
  // called when resource is loaded
  function ( object ) {

    this.scene.add( object );

  },
  // called when loading is in progresses
  function ( xhr ) {

    console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );

  },
  // called when loading has errors
  function ( error ) {

    console.log( 'An error happened' );

  }
);
```

Comment: why `typeof THREE.OBJLoader` ? Isn't it been loaded as a separate module?

Comment: was just a check to see if the OBJLoader was recognized as a function and not as a null element

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing it with

`import * as OBJLoader from 'three-obj-loader';`

You can implement it like this:

`const objLoader = new OBJLoader();`

There's no reason to try to put it inside the `THREE` namespace. Additionally, I think performing `OBJLoader(THREE);` as you are in line 3 isn't really doing anything.